# Как в Swift 4 убрать точку с 0 при вычислении на калькуляторе?

Tags: swift, swift4

Как в Swift 4 убрать точку с 0 при вычислении на калькуляторе?
Делаю калькулятор[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можешь попробовать использовать форматировку строки.

```
display.text = String(format: "%g", newValue)
```

Comment: Получилось, большое спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Можно банально обернуть в `Int(36.0)`